# Move file from mainfolder to subfolder failed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

A simple script for moving a file vom the documentdirectory to a subdirectory don't work

> Moved failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)

```
var fileManager : NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var folderDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

func moveFile(fileDirSource: String, fileDirDestination: String, fileName: String) -> Bool
{
    var error: NSError?
    
    var filePathSource : String = folderDocuments
    if(fileDirSource != "")
    {
        filePathSource = folderDocuments.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileDirSource)
    }
    
    
    filePathSource = filePathSource.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    
    var filePathDestination : String = folderDocuments.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileDirDestination)
    filePathDestination = filePathDestination.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    
    println(filePathSource)
    println(filePathDestination)
    
    if self.checkIfFileExists(filePathSource)
    {
        if fileManager.moveItemAtPath(filePathSource, toPath: filePathDestination, error: &error)
        {
            println("Move successful")
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            println("Moved failed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

I try it with the Simulator of Xcode. The following function returns true, because the file exist in the Documentdirectory. Also the destinationfolder exist and the destinationfolder is empty.

```
func checkIfFileExists(fileNameWithPath: String) -> Bool
{
    return fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(fileNameWithPath)
    
}
```

Here are the two pathvalues

SourcePath

> /Users/rwollenschlaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/111A9376-75A8-45CD-86DA-BDA53D8B4EDB/data/Containers/Data/Application/5C01BB3D-586E-409D-9378-BEFFE91A410B/Documents/done_123.txt

DestinationPath

> /Users/rwollenschlaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/111A9376-75A8-45CD-86DA-BDA53D8B4EDB/data/Containers/Data/Application/5C01BB3D-586E-409D-9378-BEFFE91A410B/Documents/Input/done_123.txt

Here is the function of the AppDelegate, where i start to move the file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    println("App Path: \(dirPaths)")
    
    // Folder for the files would be created if not exist
    var fileshandling = Filehandling()
    var arrFoldername = ["Inbox","Outbox","Files"]
    
    for foldername in arrFoldername
    {
        if(!fileshandling.checkIfFolderExist(foldername))
        {
            fileshandling.mkdir(foldername)
        }
        else
        {
            println("The Folder " + foldername + " exists")
        }
    }
    
    fileshandling.moveFile("", fileDirDestination: "Input", fileName: "done_123.txt")
    println("UUID string: \(uuid)")
    
    return true
}
```

This is the console in Xcode, when i start to run my app

> App Path: > [/Users/rwollenschlaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/111A9376-75A8-45CD-86DA-BDA53D8B4EDB/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE93DA6D-8125-48B8-B4EB-C9B706A3A1DA/Documents]
>
> The Folder Inbox exists
>
> The Folder Outbox exists
>
> The Folder Files exists
>
> /Users/rwollenschlaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/111A9376-75A8-45CD-86DA-BDA53D8B4EDB/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE93DA6D-8125-48B8-B4EB-C9B706A3A1DA/Documents/done_123.txt
>
> /Users/rwollenschlaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/111A9376-75A8-45CD-86DA-BDA53D8B4EDB/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE93DA6D-8125-48B8-B4EB-C9B706A3A1DA/Documents/Input/done_123.txt
>
> Moved failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)
>
> UUID string: 027E0494-3E24-45B8-A2AC-7E3501BED78A

Here is the screenshot from the terminal of the documentfolder
[image: The Terminalscreenshot]

Comment: educated guess: the `Input` directory does not exist

Comment: by the hell. The folder is Inbox and not Input. Oh my god. Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cocoa error 4` here means that you are trying to move a file that does not exist or this could also mean that the target directory does not exists.